# SQL Server: Parent-Child with Pivot Data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I do not have very good knowledge in advanced SQL. I have been facing a problem for a long time to show data in a specific way.

Desired output as follows

```
+-------------+------------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+--+
| DisplayText | Type       | BC   | AK   | NH   | 2010 FYA | BC   | AK   | NH   | 2011 FYA | BC   | AK   | NH   | 2012 FYA |  |
+-------------+------------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+--+
| Key Drugs   |   GROUP    | NULL | NULL | NULL |          | NULL | NULL | NULL |          | NULL | NULL | NULL |          |  |
| R&D         |   LINEITEM | 10   | 99   | 12   |          | 56   | 26   | 21   |          | 11   | 87   | 71   |          |  |
| Net Revenue |   LINEITEM | 12   | 20   | 17   |          | 79   | 12   | 22   |          | 55   | 17   | 27   |          |  |
| Key Fin     |   GROUP    | NULL | NULL | NULL |          | NULL | NULL | NULL |          | NULL | NULL | NULL |          |  |
| Diluted     |   LINEITEM | 10   | 99   | 12   |          | 56   | 26   | 21   |          | 11   | 87   | 71   |          |  |
+-------------+------------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+--+
```

I have two tables called `tblCSMModels` & `tblOutputDetl`. The `tblCSMModels` table has parent child data, the relationship is established with `ID` and `ParentID`.

Screenshot of the table with sample data:

[image]

Group are master and line items are child. each group may have multiple child line item and a group may child group too which can have another line items as child.

Here I am showing the table structures and sample data as a result anyone can reproduce this at their end.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblCSMModels]
(
    [Ticker] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentID] [int] NULL,
    [DisplayText] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Type] [nchar](10) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ON 
GO

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) 
VALUES (N'ANAB', 1, 0, N'Key Drugs', N'GROUP     ')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type])  
VALUES (N'ANAB', 2, 1, N'R&D, Proforma', N'LINEITEM  ')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) 
VALUES (N'ANAB', 3, 1, N'Net Revenue', N'LINEITEM  ')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) 
VALUES (N'ANAB', 4, 0, N'Key Fin', N'GROUP     ')

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblCSMModels] ([Ticker], [ID], [ParentID], [DisplayText], [Type]) 
VALUES (N'ANAB', 5, 4, N'Diluted', N'LINEITEM  ')
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tblOutputDetl]
(
    [Ticker] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Section] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [LineItem] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Broker] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Period] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [ItemValue] [decimal](18, 2) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

INSERT INTO tblOutputDetl (Ticker, Section, LineItem, Broker, Period, ItemValue)
VALUES ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2010 FYA',10),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2011 FYA',56),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','BC','2012 FYA',11),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2010 FYA',99),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2011 FYA',26),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','AK','2012 FYA',87),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2010 FYA',12),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2011 FYA',21),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','R&D','NH','2012 FYA',71),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2010 FYA',12),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2011 FYA',79),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2012 FYA',55),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2010 FYA',20),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2011 FYA',12),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2012 FYA',17),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2010 FYA',21),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2011 FYA',22),
       ('ANAB','Consensus Model','Net Revenue','NH','2012 FYA',27),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2010 FYA',10),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2011 FYA',56),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','BC','2012 FYA',11),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2010 FYA',99),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2011 FYA',26),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','AK','2012 FYA',87),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2010 FYA',12),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2011 FYA',21),
       ('ANAB','Key Drugs','Diluted','NH','2012 FYA',71)
```

This way tried but could not write the correct SQL which produces the desired output.

```
;WITH DirectReports (Ticker, ID, ParentID, DisplayText, Type) AS
(
    SELECT Ticker, ID, ParentID, DisplayText, Type
    FROM tblCSMModels AS e
    WHERE isnull(ParentID ,0) = 0

    UNION ALL

    SELECT e.Ticker, e.ID, e.ParentID, e.DisplayText, e.Type
    FROM tblCSMModels AS e
    INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d ON e.ParentID = d.ID
)

SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT r.Ticker, r.DisplayText, r.Type, d.Broker, d.ItemValue, d.Period
     FROM DirectReports r 
     INNER JOIN tblOutputDetl d ON (r.Ticker = d.Ticker AND r.DisplayText = d.LineItem)
     WHERE r.Ticker = 'ANAB') t
PIVOT
    (MAX(ItemValue)
        FOR Broker IN ([BC], [AK], [NH])
    ) AS P
```

Basically I want to show parent data and their related child. Broker will be coming horizontally and **ItemValue** will be placed under broker. after showing all broker horizontally then one Period will come say 2010 FYA.

Period will be sorted like **2010 FYA, 2011 FYA, 2012 FYA, 1Q 2013A,2Q 2013A,3Q 2013A,4Q 2013A, 2013 FYA**.

This way specific period wise Broker data will be shown horizontally. so all brokers and period will be showing  horizontally. see my output first at top with in ASCII table.

Under each period of every row SUM of Broker value should be shown.

I can understand to get desired output SQL will be very complex and I am not being able to write that SQL. So my request please some one help me. I badly stuck at this SQL from morning.

Thanks in advance.

### EDIT

```
 ;WITH DirectReports (Ticker, ID, ParentID, DisplayText, Type) AS
   (
       SELECT Ticker, ID, ParentID, DisplayText, Type
       FROM tblCSMModels AS e
       WHERE isnull(ParentID ,0) = 0
            
       UNION ALL
            
       SELECT e.Ticker, e.ID, e.ParentID, e.DisplayText, e.Type
       FROM tblCSMModels AS e
       INNER JOIN DirectReports AS d ON e.ParentID = d.ID
   )
  ,cte as (
  SELECT r.Ticker, r.DisplayText, r.Type, d.Broker, d.ItemValue, d.Period
        FROM DirectReports r 
        left JOIN tblOutputDetl d ON (r.Ticker = d.Ticker AND 
    d.LineItem = case when CHARINDEX(',',r.DisplayText)>0 then SUBSTRING(r.DisplayText,1,CHARINDEX(',',r.DisplayText)-1) else r.DisplayText end)
        WHERE r.Ticker = 'ANAB')
  ,cte1 as (
   SELECT * 
   FROM
       (SELECT Ticker, DisplayText, Type, Broker, ItemValue, Period
        from cte) t
   PIVOT
       (MAX(ItemValue)
           FOR Broker IN ([BC], [AK], [NH])
       ) AS P)
  ,cte2 as (
  SELECT *, Period+'_BC' as Col, BC as Val FROM cte1 
   UNION
   SELECT *, Period+'_AK' as Col,AK as Val  FROM cte1
    UNION
   SELECT *, Period+'_NH' as Col,NH as Val  FROM cte1
   UNION
   SELECT *, Period as Col,NULL as Val  FROM cte1
   )
   select DisplayText,TYPE,[2010 FYA_BC] [BC],[2010 FYA_AK] [AK], [2010 FYA_NH] [NH],[2010 FYA],[2011 FYA_BC] [BC],[2011 FYA_AK] [AK],
   [2011 FYA_NH] [NH],[2011 FYA],[2012 FYA_BC] [BC],[2012 FYA_AK] [AK],[2012 FYA_NH] [NH],[2012 FYA]
    from 
   (select DisplayText,type,col,val
   from cte2) s
   PIVOT ( 
   max(val) 
   for Col in 
   ([2010 FYA_BC],[2010 FYA_AK], [2010 FYA_NH],[2010 FYA],[2011 FYA_BC],[2011 FYA_AK],
   [2011 FYA_NH],[2011 FYA],[2012 FYA_BC],[2012 FYA_AK],[2012 FYA_NH],[2012 FYA]) ) AS pvt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To produce your desired results, I worked with your original query, but made changes in the following areas:

Problems with your sample data:

- 'LineItem' in tblOutputDetl would better be the ID from tblCSMModels, not the DisplayText.  I won't change your sample data structure, but because the 'R&D' label does not match, I am working off of a dataset in tblCSMModels that changes 'R&D, Proforma' to just 'R&D'.
- Your tblOutputDetl data has 'NH' as the type for all entries of 'net revenue', but your desired output clearly indicates that you intended to input the three different types as with the other two line-items.  I am working with a dataset that changes this.

Problems in your core approach:

- No group-level item is in tblOutputDetl, so if you want to display it in the final output, you should be left joining on it in your final query, not inner joining it.
- You basically want a multi-column pivot.  Generally, you do this with filters inside of aggregations.  Hence the various `max(case ...)` lines in the code below.
- You have an ordering problem that your sample data isn't describing well.  You want your output ordered basically showing the tree structure, with parents above their children.
  Your sample data has the identifier already ordered in this way. But of course, if you add an item, it may come out of order. In that case, you can't depend on the 'id' column for ordering. What I've done is create a hierarchy field in the recursive query.  You can order by this field.

Minor changes in the output:

- I've added a 'level' field mostly to add some outlining features to the 'DisplayText' in the output.
- I've changed the format of your output a bit.  The year is in the column names instead of creating a blank dividing column.  I've also grouped by ticker, instead of filtering by it.

Here's the code:

```
with DirectReports as (

    select      Ticker, 
                ID, 
                ParentID, 
                hierarchy = format(id,'0000'), 
                level = 0,
                DisplayText, 
                Type
    from        tblCSMModels e
    where       isnull(ParentID, 0) = 0

    union all
    select      e.Ticker, 
                e.ID, 
                e.ParentID, 
                hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + format(e.id,'0000'), 
                level = level + 1,
                e.DisplayText, 
                e.Type
    from        tblCSMModels e
    join        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
)

select      r.Ticker,
            DisplayText = replicate('-' + char(9), r.level) + r.DisplayText, 
            r.Type, 
            r.hierarchy,
            r.level,
            [BC 2010] = max(case when d.Broker = 'bc' and d.Period = '2010 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [AK 2010] = max(case when d.Broker = 'ak' and d.Period = '2010 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [NH 2010] = max(case when d.Broker = 'nh' and d.Period = '2010 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [BC 2011] = max(case when d.Broker = 'bc' and d.Period = '2011 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [AK 2011] = max(case when d.Broker = 'ak' and d.Period = '2011 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [NH 2011] = max(case when d.Broker = 'nh' and d.Period = '2011 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [BC 2012] = max(case when d.Broker = 'bc' and d.Period = '2012 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [AK 2012] = max(case when d.Broker = 'ak' and d.Period = '2012 fya' then d.ItemValue end),
            [NH 2012] = max(case when d.Broker = 'nh' and d.Period = '2012 fya' then d.ItemValue end)
from        DirectReports r 
left join   tblOutputDetl d 
                on r.Ticker = d.Ticker 
                and r.DisplayText = d.LineItem
group by    r.Ticker,
            r.DisplayText,
            r.Type,
            r.hierarchy,
            r.level
order by    r.hierarchy;
```

With the corrected sample date, this results in:

```
+--------+---------------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| Ticker | DisplayText   | Type       | hierarchy | level | BC 2010 | AK 2010 | NH 2010 | BC 2011 | AK 2011 | NH 2011 | BC 2012 | AK 2012 | NH 2012 |
+--------+---------------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+  
| ANAB   | Key Drugs     | GROUP      | 0001      | 0     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| ANAB   | - R&D         | LINEITEM   | 0001.0002 | 1     | 10.00   | 99.00   | 12.00   | 56.00   | 26.00   | 21.00   | 11.00   | 87.00   | 71.00   |
| ANAB   | - Net Revenue | LINEITEM   | 0001.0003 | 1     | 12.00   | 20.00   | 21.00   | 79.00   | 12.00   | 22.00   | 55.00   | 17.00   | 27.00   |
| ANAB   | Key Fin       | GROUP      | 0004      | 0     | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    | NULL    |
| ANAB   | - Diluted     | LINEITEM   | 0004.0005 | 1     | 10.00   | 99.00   | 12.00   | 56.00   | 26.00   | 21.00   | 11.00   | 87.00   | 71.00   |
+--------+---------------+------------+-----------+-------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

Final note: You're basically doing reporting tasks in SQL.  Data and some business-logic stuff should be done in SQL, but reporting and presentation logic is best done in a tool designed for it, such as Excel, SSRS, Crystal Reports, a website, etc.

---

## Edit:

So you mention in your comments that you don't want to type in each individual broker and period.  Well, I definitely repeat my 'final note' above: you're doing presentation logic in sql-server.  That is not going to work out well for you in the long run.

Nevertheless, just as a puzzle I often like responding to this kind of need.  The only thing that's going to work for you inside sql-server is dynamic sql.  Dynamic sql can be dangerous if you're not careful to fend off sql-injection attacks.  And it's not good because the query-optimizer can't save the plan.  So consider those things as well as using another tool before implementing my use of dynamic sql below.

The first step is to pump your direct reports output into a temp table:

```
with DirectReports as (

    select      Ticker, 
                ID, 
                ParentID, 
                hierarchy = format(id,'0000'), 
                level = 0,
                DisplayText, 
                Type
    from        tblCSMModels e
    where       isnull(ParentID, 0) = 0

    union all
    select      e.Ticker, 
                e.ID, 
                e.ParentID, 
                hierarchy = d.hierarchy + '.' + format(e.id,'0000'), 
                level = level + 1,
                e.DisplayText, 
                e.Type
    from        tblCSMModels e
    join        DirectReports d on e.ParentID = d.ID
)

select      * 
into        #hierarchy;
from        DirectReports;
```

The next step is to build the sql column logic for the broker-period pairs.  Plug it into a string variable.  This is the start of the dynamic sql.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max) = '';

select      @sql += '  ' +  
                ',[' + b.Broker + ' ' + p.Period + '] ' + 
                '= max(' + 
                      'case when d.Broker = ''' + b.Broker + ''' ' + 
                            'and d.period = ''' + p.period + ''' ' + 
                            'then d.itemValue ' + 
                            'end' + 
                   ')' + char(13) + char(10)
from        (select distinct broker from ##tblOutputDel) b
cross join  (select distinct period from ##tblOutputDel) p;
```

Then take that sql piece and wrap it into a larger more complete statement:

```
set @sql = '
    select      
      h.Ticker
      ,DisplayText = replicate(''-'' + char(9), h.level) + h.DisplayText
      ,h.Type
      ,h.hierarchy
      ,h.level
      ' + @sql + '      
    from        #hierarchy h 
    left join   #tblOutputDel d 
                    on h.Ticker = d.Ticker 
                    and h.DisplayText = d.LineItem
    group by    h.Ticker,
                h.DisplayText,
                h.Type,
                h.hierarchy,
                h.level
    order by    h.hierarchy;
';
```

Finally, execute the statement:

```
exec(@sql);
```

Notice how complicated it's all getting?  I repeat, you're doing presentation logic in a database.  You're going to have this need in a different form many times in the future.  It'll be less complicated to build a presentation layer that queries your database and then manipulates things from there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer and help but i do not want to hard code like `[BC 2010] = max(case when d.Broker = 'bc' and d.Period = '2010 fya' then d.ItemValue end),` because there could be many brokers and period is also not limited from 2010 FY to 2012 FY. so how to write query where nothing will be hard coded?

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i am not looking for that kind of output which your new code produced. I want to show all Brokers in column and one period which is 2010 FYA. again want to show all Brokers in column and one period which is 2011 FYA. period should appear order wise. 2010 FYA is small so it would come first and then 2011 FYA. broker value will be for 2010 FYA and next broker value will be for 2011 FYA. in this fashion data will be printed. my periods are not limited to 2012 FYA. in real table there are many other periods.

Comment: IN my edit section i shared a code which is composed by some one. it generate output what i am looking for but there is Broker & periods are hard coded which need to be dynamic. can you please make that code more better where period & broker will not be hard coded. looking for your help and answer. Thanks